# Timeout error when result of a transaction is used as parameter

Tags: c#, concurrency, ado.net, transactions

I have following code that uses SqlTransaction

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    int logID = HelperClass.InsertException(connection, 1, DateTime.Now, "Y", "test", "test", 1, 1, transaction);
    LogSearch logSearch = new LogSearch();
    logSearch.LogID = 258;

    Collection<Log> logs = HelperClass.GetLogs(logSearch, connectionString);
}
```

This code is throwing the following **exception**.

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

However if I pass a hard coded value for LogID, there is no exception.

**QUESTION**

1. Why does exception come when I pass logID (result from InsertException()) ?
2. Please explain why there is NO exception when I pass a `hard coded` value as LogID

Note: InsertException() uses a connection with `SqlTransaction` whereas GetLogs() uses a new connection without any transaction

**UPDATED QUESTION**

The Business Layer code does not use `Transaction`. I need to call the Business Layer methods in my Unit Testing code shown above (for integration testing). How can we apply transaction to UT code (for integration testing)  even though the Business Layer does not use transaction? From @jbl answer, it seems like, it is not at all possible to use transaction in Unit Testing. How can we apply transaction for UT code.

**CODE**

```
public static class HelperClass
{
    public static Collection<Log> GetLogs(LogSearch logSearch, string connectionString)
    {
        Collection<Log> logs = new Collection<Log>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string commandText = "SELECT * FROM Application_EX WHERE application_ex_id = @application_ex_id";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                //Parameter value setting
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", logSearch.LogID);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return logs;

    }

    public static Int16 InsertException(SqlConnection connection, Int16 applicationID, DateTime createdDate, string isInternalLocationIndicator, string exceptionDescription, string operation, Int16 severityLevelNumber, Int16 exceptionTypeCode, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {


        Int16 newLogID = 0;
        string commandText = @"INSERT INTO Application_Ex
                            VALUES (@severity_level_nbr, @appl_service_id, @ex_internal_appl_ind, 
                            @application_ex_txt,@ex_location_txt,@create_ts,@application_ex_code);
                            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [LogIdentity];";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection, transaction))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@severity_level_nbr", severityLevelNumber);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appl_service_id", applicationID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex_internal_appl_ind", isInternalLocationIndicator);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_txt", exceptionDescription);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex_location_txt", operation);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create_ts", createdDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_code", exceptionTypeCode);

            newLogID = Convert.ToInt16(command.ExecuteScalar(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        return newLogID;

    }
}
```

Comment: You state that "The Business Layer code (HelperClass.InsertException) does not use `Transaction`", but `command = new SqlCommand(..., transaction)` clearly _does_ use the transaction. This is your problem, as `LogSearch` is trying to select the *uncommitted* (and therefore locked) data inserted by `HelperClass`.

Answer (score 7):

QUESTION

1. Why does exception come when I pass logID (result from InsertException()) ?
2. Please explain why there is NO exception when I pass a hard coded value as LogID

ANSWERS

1. When a new record is inserted with using a transaction, that means the new record is not finally committed until you yourself commit the transaction. Until that time the new record is LOCKED, which means that any query that touches that new record will be suspended until a timeout occurs. In your case, the call to the method GetLogs is executed while the transaction is still running, and that method searches for the newly inserted record-id. Since the row is locked, your GetLogs call will wait until the timeout occurs, which results in a timeout exception.
2. In the case of a hard coded value, the call to GetLogs will search for the existing record with the corresponding id. Since you are searching for a PK-value, SQL does not have to search all rows, since it is the PK. Therefore, the existing row is found, and returned, all in a separate transaction, since the transactions are not overlapping in the data they touch.

Suppose your method GetLogs was searching the table on another column, a non-pk column (say for example application_message), then the whole table would have to be read to find a row (or rows) with the corresponding value for application_message. This would result in a query that always touches the newly inserted locked row, and then also with a hard coded (application_message) value your would get a timeout exception. This I added just to clarify the locking, and when SQL does or does not need to touch the locked row(s).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying that we cannot apply transaction while integration testing with `Unit Testing` code?

Comment: You can try to surround you testing code with a TransactionScope, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx. This will run your connections in the same transaction, in an ambient way. Not really sure if it will work since the connection of the first query is still open in your code when you call the method with the second query. Worth a try though.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that's because `HelperClass.GetLogs(logSearch, connectionString);` instantiate a new connection out of scope of your transaction :

You may, at your will :

- have your helper class accept the connection object holding the transaction instead of a connection string
- or replace `"SELECT * FROM Application_EX WHERE application_ex_id = @application_ex_id"` with `"SELECT * FROM Application_EX with (nolock) WHERE application_ex_id = @application_ex_id"`

note that the second case would sometimes return incorrect values, and would not return values you are currently inserting in your transaction

Hope this will help

Comment: I don't understand why it should return an exception. The data is not committed in the first call. That is fine. But why is there an exception?

Comment: Because the corresponding rows are locked until the transaction is completed, preventing the table from being queryied. Your helper waits for a lock release which will never come (as the release should happen after the helper has successfully run)

Comment: Please explain why there is NO exception when I pass a hard coded value as LogID

Comment: @Lijo : that's because the system is able to compute that there is no conflict between the hard coded value rows and the values currently being inserted. So it can safely return the hard coded value rows. Those will be the same whether you commit or rollback your transaction. This is a row level lock.

Comment: @Lijo you may start by reading about transaction isolation levels : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx